# vim key map suddenly changed. How to change it back?

Tags: vim, keyboard

Starting just today, after editing a source file for a few minutes vim suddenly responds differently to my keys than I expect it to.  I don't have many details as I saved and quit lest it eat my file.

I'm concerned it could be something wrong with the keyboard on my Acer Inspire E15, but typing this post works just fine.

One thing that happened is that entering ^P (Constrol-P) pasted a word, rather than moving to the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

First, Ctrl-P doesn't move to the previous line, <kbd>k</kbd> usually does (in normal mode).

Next time:

1. First, observe in what *mode* you are: normal, insert, command-line.
2. Then check any mappings, for example with `:verbose nmap <C-p>`. You can also list *all* mappings with `:map | :map!`

Another pitfall is if you accidentally have `:set paste`; then, no mappings at all suddenly apply!

Also, consider the environment: Are you in a terminal, or do you use GUI GVIM; do you have any related apps (`screen` / `tmux`, or AutoKey) that may distort key bindings? Do you connect remotely through VNC / remote desktop; these sometimes can have "sticky keys" (like Shift-Lock) wreaking havoc.

And finally, real hardware failures are very rare :-)